# Force redirect to action url in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

In an ASP.NET MVC3 webapplication how to force redirect to an action url?

I want something like this:

```
if(i==0)
{
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Edit:
 I need to call it from a normal class not a controller

thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1):

That's quite correct. Just add the return

```
if(i==0)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I get an error The name 'RedirectToAction' does not exist in the current context (sorry I might have edited your answer by mistake)

Comment: I guess you should put some more code then. This error seems that you are not doing the call inside an action method of a contorller

Comment: Try to put [`using System.Web.Mvc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx)

Comment: If your class don't derive form the controller class you can't do much. It is meant to be there

Answer (score 1):

This is a controller action, so you should **not** return it from a method in a dependent class. Let your dependent class return a value and the controller can decide where and how the flow should proceed.